# Using [FromQuery] Name property on complex type

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We can use `[FromQuery(Name"param")]` in a controller action to specify how the passed parameter will be used in the uri as in :

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult GetPeople([FromQuery(Name="page")] int pageNumber, [FromQuery(Name="size")] int pageSize)
{
     //Do things
}
```

How to use that in the case of using a complex type such as `PeoplePaginationParameters` where :

```
public class PaginationParameters
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set;}
    public int PageSize { get; set;}
}
```

Is there any thing like :

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult GetPeople([FromQuery(Name="page", Name="size")] PaginationParameters paginationParameters)
{
    //Do things
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `[FromQuery(Name="parameterName")]` on each property of the complex type :

```
public class PaginationParameters
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "page")]
     public int PageNumber { get; set;}
    [FromQuery(Name = "size")]
    public int PageSize { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution? You cannot use this if you are using a layered architecture and requests in a different project (you'd have to pull MVC dependency onto that project).